# viewport media query works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: css

I am experimenting with the responsive design feature of css. When I set a max width of `370px` and set my container to that width, it's supposed to stay that way even if the screen's width is less. When using the developer tool in Google Chrome, it works perfectly when I set to be viewed from a desktop but when I set it to be viewed from a mobile phone it doesn't. I added the `<meta>` tags and everything. What's going on?

These are the specifications:

```
@media screen and (max-width:370px) {
    #container {
        width:370px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is copied into the question correctly?  The white space looks weird.

Comment: Do you included this meta in your page `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`  ?

Comment: If the question css code is incorrect that need to be like tib `@meta screen and (max-width: 370px){ #container {  width:370px;   }  }`

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely is that you are overwriting the values set in your media query, later on in your CSS page, for example:

```
@media screen and (max-width:370px) {
     #container {
     width:370px;
    }
}
....
#container {
   width:90%;
}
```

The CSS will overwrite equal rules in a *latest-is-retained* structure, so if anything, your media queries should be exclusive (every related rule only appears in query `{...}` blocks.

Also have the width sizes not overlap, for intance:

```
@media screen and (max-width:370px) {
     #container {
     width:370px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
     #container {
     width:600px;
    }
}
```

The second query will overwrite the first query because both return `TRUE`. 
Below is a better example of how to write the syntax:

```
@media screen and (max-width:370px) {
     #container {
     width:370px;
    }
}
@media screen (min-width:371px) and (max-width:600px) {
     #container {
     width:600px;
    }
}
```

You also only need one viewport meta tag at the top of your HTML page. Use chrome developer tool to see which CSS rules are loaded for the page and use that to establish with media queries are returning true, then you can work out why and define them more precisely.

Comment: did all this and still no fix.... went to the console and it seems that the @media query is only returning TRUE when i choose desktop view and FALSE when in mobile....

Comment: @CarlosJ. ok, then remove the "screen" reference as this is generally not needed. Also try it out on Firefox -> developer Tools -> Responsive design view (I don't know of a similar one for Google), to test out how it appears at various screen sizes on various devices.